# Running combined shell script from IPython (non-interactively)

Tags: shell, scripting, ipython

Is there a possibility to run *extended* IPython (which can be used in interactive console, see example) non-interactively as a script?
I haven't found it documented anywhere.

Example:

```
#!/magical/ipython/command --that-i-want
from __future__ import print_function
d = !date +%s
!echo $d.s $(($d.s / 1000))

files = !ls -A
for i, f in enumerate(files):
    print("File number %s is '%s'" % (i, f))
```

**Expected output should be:** (result of copy&pasting to IPython interactive console)

```
1463917269 1463917
File number 0 is '.ipynb_checkpoints'
File number 1 is 'file1.txt'
File number 2 is 'file2.txt'
```

**When shebang is `ipython` it fails with:**

```
d = !date +%s
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: I know about `runipy`, I'm interested in ipython as a scripting language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

name your file with an `.ipy` extension, and IPython will be able to run it with (most) of its syntax extensions.

Though everything IPython does is **just** syntactic sugar, you can do it in pure Python.

(Please use Python 3 also)

Comment: Thanks, `.ipy` is what I was looking for. Using Py3 whenever 3rd party library exists for the job, so Py2 for bigger projects still.

Answer (score 1):

You can run this file.

`vi shebang.py`

```
get_ipython().run_cell("""
from __future__ import print_function
d = !date +%s
!echo $d.s $(($d.s / 1000))

files = !ls -A
for i, f in enumerate(files):
    print("File number %s is '%s'" % (i, f))
""")
```

and

`ipython shebang.py`